# Permissão para shutdown!

Tags: linux, bash, mint

Como faço para dar permissão a executar o comando `shutdown` ao user ?

Estou usando o OS Linux Mint 13.

Comment: `sudo` não resolve o seu problema?

Comment: não, ele pede a senha do root!

Comment: Por que você não adiciona seu usuário no sudoers?

Comment: Já adicionei, mas  não funciona, manda um ex por favor!

Comment: Creio que está pergunta seja off-topic para o SOpt, talvez um lugar para perguntar seja o http://unix.stackexchange.com ou http://askubuntu.com (Mint é uma "fork" do Ubuntu)

Answer (score 1):

Uma das alternativas é editar o arquivo /etc/sudoers e incluir nesse arquivo a seguinte linha:

```
user host = (root) NOPASSWD: /sbin/shutdown
```

Onde:

**user** = usuário que você deseja dar a permissão ao shutdown sem solicitar a senha

**host** = nome do host (execute o comando hostname para saber)

Para editar o arquivo /etc/sudoers utilize a ferramenta visudo, veja abaixo:

```
sudo visudo -f /etc/sudoers
```

Um exemplo real (meu computador de backup):

```
luiz storage = (root) NOPASSWD: /sbin/shutdown
```

Executando o comando:

```
sudo /sbin/shutdown -r now
```

O comando acima dará um shutdown imediato e fará uma reinicialização do computador. **Nenhuma senha será solicitada.**